# Project Euler #8 c++ from beginner

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008

### I Don't Understand why I am not getting the correct answer to this problem

I just started c++ and my friends told me about projecteuler so I started doing its questions.

**Question 8 is:**

Find the greatest product of five consecutive digits in the 1000-digit number.

73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450.

**This is my Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
char num[]  ="7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
int a, b, c, d = 0;
for (a = 0; a<=995; a++)
{
    c = 1;
    for (b = 0; b<=4; b++)
    {
        c *= num[a+b];
    }

    if (c > d) d = c;
}

std::cout<<d<<std::endl;
system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately it spits out 570394440. Not only is this incorrect, but its way too big. I am having trouble finding the problem in my code, and solution to the problem.

*Any help is appreciated!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the

```
c*= num[a+b] - '0';
```

How about a strlen(num) in the if condition.

Of course the num[x] is the ascii value, subtractig with the '0', decimal 48, will give you the correct numerical value.

E.g.

```
c = '2' * '2';
```

amounts to 50 times 50. If you subtract the value of '0' (48) it becomes the proper numerical operation.

So

```
c = ('2' - '0')*('2' - '0');
```

Is the operation

```
c = 2 * 2
```

For the particular numerical values see the wikipedia entry on ascii.

Comment: Was just about to post this, pretty sure you've got the answer here.

Comment: @ Captain Giraffe, why would "subtractig with the '0', decimal 48," if it is an ascii value give me the right answer? I am not doubting you, because it did work, but why?

Answer (score 1):

My Python Code....

```
digits ="7316717653.....0752963450"
max = 0
for i in range(0, len(digits)-5):
    prod = 1
    for j in range(0, 5):
        prod *= int(digits[i+j])
    if (prod > max):
        max = prod
print max
```

this code can be optimized using maps. :)

Comment: This is `Python` and not `C++`

Answer (score 0):

If someone still need help. Check the top answer.(as of posting it was by "Doorknob of Snow')

[Project Euler #8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20710051/project-euler-8/20710143?noredirect=1#20710143)

Answer (score -2):

c*= num[a+b] - '0'; //fix this as @Captain Giraffe answer
and  replace for (b = 0; b<=4; b++) by for (b = 0; b<4; b++)

declare the value of c and d variable as long long d=0,c;