# Project Euler #8

Tags: c

I tried to solve the problem on my own but got stuck after a while so looked at the solution.[Question #8](http://projecteuler.net/problem=8). 
 And this is what I got.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char str[] =
    "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
    "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"
    "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"
    "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"
    "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"
    "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"
    "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"
    "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"
    "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"
    "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"
    "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"
    "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"
    "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"
    "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"
    "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"
    "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"
    "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"
    "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"
    "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"
    "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
  size_t len = sizeof str - 1;
  size_t i;
  unsigned max = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < len-4; i++) {
    unsigned p = 1;
    size_t j;

    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      p *= (unsigned)(str[i+j]-'0');
    }
    if (p > max) {
      max = p;
    }
  }
  printf("%u\n", max);
  return 0;
}
```

**My Problem :** I didn't understand why there was -'0' in this line

```
 p *= (unsigned)(str[i+j]-'0');
```

Sorry if my question is very stupid. But I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
'0' - '0' == 0
'1' - '0' == 1
'2' - '0' == 2
etc.
```

Basically, it's for converting a `char` to its corresponding digit.

An explanation is that characters map directly to ASCII values:

```
'0' == 48
'1' == 49
'2' == 50
etc.
```

And the values are sequential. Therefore, when you subtract the lowest digit, you get the position after that digit, which will also be the int value of the digit.

Comment: Perfectly explained. Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Because that large block of digits is a string, each character is a text representation of a number rather than the number itself.  If we take, for example the point at which `i = 0` and `j = 0`, then `str[i+j]` is `'7'`, note the quotes.

Now, characters in C are typically represented in ASCII, where every character is represented by a number from 0 to 255.  `'7'` when converted to its numeric representation is equal to 55.  See here for a table of ASCII values: http://www.asciitable.com/.

Note, now that all the numbers are sequential.  The value of `'0'` is 48 and 57 minus 48 is 7.  Subtracting `'0'` from a character representing a digit is a way to convert it back into the numeric representation of the digit.

Comment: `"Now, characters in C are typically represented in ASCII…"` Actually, characters in the USA are typically represented in ASCII, right? :-D

Comment: @Fiddling Bits  Yes, characters in the USA are typically represented in ASCII - hence the 'A' for "American".  Also by the C spec, for `'0'` to `'9'`, `character - '0'` converts to 0 to 9 regardless of encoding employed.

Comment: @chux Just trying to be funny… but not succeeding apparently. :-D

Comment: @Fiddling Bits Yeah, best if we don't quit our day jobs, too.  Coding is easy - comedy is tough

Comment: "Actually, characters in the USA are typically represented in ASCII, right?" -- No. Characters in the USA are typically represented graphically.